# Conflicting Scope: Global Functions and Class Methods of the Same Name

Tags: actionscript-3, function, methods, scope, global

My question deals directly with ActionScript 3, although it could possibly appear in other languages.

Consider the global *trace* function found in AS3. Calling the method requires no imports and is globally available from all classes.

```
class A {

    public function A() {
        trace("Hello, A!"); // Hello, A!
    }

}
```

Now, what if I create my own class method of the same name? In AS3, if I have a class method *trace* and then make a call to *trace* elsewhere in my class, the call is made to the class method over the global function. Essentially, I've blocked my ability to call the global trace method.

```
class B {

    public function B() {
        trace("Hello, B!"); // no output
    }

    public function trace(s:String):void {
        // do something else.
    }

}
```

Now, I know the obvious answer is to say, "don't create a class method called *trace*." But what if I'm unaware of the existence of the global *trace* function? Or what if I have a desire to "override" or "block" the global function? Is doing so bad programming? Or is this just another example of how AS3 is a poor object oriented language?

Comment: Hiding the most common names is bad in any language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function `trace` was not `public` you could using the `public` [namespace](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Namespace.html) to call the original function :

```
class B {
    public function B() {
        // call the trace function that is defined in the public namespace
        public::trace("Hello, B!"); // output "Hello, B!"
    }

    // here the function is protected so not into the public namespace
    protected function trace(s:String):void {
        // do something else.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

import flash.uitls.*;

then you can use

```
(getDefinitionByName('trace') as Function)('Global trace.');
```

Answer (score 0):

"But what if I'm unaware of the existence of the global trace function?"

I'd see this more as an indication that you haven't yet done due diligence in your language research than as a fault in the language itself.  There are very few top-level names and keywords in AS3, and I think it's fair to say that if you're interested in learning a language you should at least familiarize yourself with that top level.

Comment: I think 'trace' was actually a bad example. I had a real world situation just a few days ago with the 'Vector' function that sits in the global namespace. I had a legacy project (written before Vector was introduced) that used a math-related class called - guess what - Vector. I needed to recompile for a newer Flash version, and bam! the project doesn't want to compile and I get errors all over the place whereever that Vector class is used. I agree with the OP that this is poor design on the part of Adobe. Why did they not put the Vector function in its own package?

Comment: @RIAstar Vector is an odd case in that it can be thought of as a primitive like int or uint.  They come close to being true arrays in the sense of being contiguous blocks of memory of size N, where N equals the size of the datatype required.  This is in contrast to the AS3 "Array" which is more of an untyped ArrayList.  Anyway, primitives don't belong in packages and as such Vector doesn't live in a package.  It's unfortunate for sure, but I understand why it works that way.

Comment: Neither Array nor Vector is a primitive, because `1 == 1` or `"a" == "a"` evaluates to 'true', but `[1] == [1]` does not. They are built-in (or top-level) collections.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method would be to change the place where the name binding to the global identifier happens, like with the following wrapper class:

```
class B {
    public function B() {
        Globals.global_trace("Hello, B!"); // delegates to global trace()
    }
    public function trace(s:String):void {
        // do something else.
    }
}

class Globals {
    public function global_trace(...args) {
        // class B's identifiers are now irrelevant for the name lookup
        trace.apply(null, args);
    }
}
```

A more localized approach would be to rebind the global symbol before hiding it:

```
private static var _trace:* = trace; // rebind global trace

public function trace(...args) {
    _trace.apply(null, args);
}
```